# How to return the weight and the corresponding index in this Knapsack java code?

Tags: java, knapsack-problem

So I'm looking at this code here from [this website](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/) regarding the knapsack 0-1 problem.

I want to modify the program they provide so that it returns which values were selected along with the corresponding index. For example, for this situation, the solution outputs 390 but I want it to *also* print out the values that have been selected. So in this case, I want it to print:

```
Items selected :
#2 60
#3 90
#5 240
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
// A Dynamic Programming based solution for 0-1 Knapsack problem
class Knapsack
{

    // A utility function that returns maximum of two integers
    static int max(int a, int b) { return (a > b)? a : b; }

// Returns the maximum value that can be put in a knapsack of capacity W
    static int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n)
    {
        int i, w;
    int K[][] = new int[n+1][W+1];
            int[] selected = new int[n + 1];

    // Build table K[][] in bottom up manner
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (w = 0; w <= W; w++)
        {
            if (i==0 || w==0){
                //selected[i] = 1;
                K[i][w] = 0;
            }
            else if (wt[i-1] <= w){
                selected[i] = 1;
                K[i][w] = max(val[i-1] + K[i-1][w-wt[i-1]], K[i-1][w]);
            }
            else{
                selected[i]=0;
                K[i][w] = K[i-1][w];
            }
        }
    }
     System.out.println("\nItems selected : ");
        for (int x = 1; x < n + 1; x++)
            if (selected[x] == 1)
                System.out.print(x +" ");
        System.out.println();

    return K[n][W];
    }


    // Driver program to test above function
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int val[] = new int[]{300,60,90,100,240};
    int wt[] = new int[]{50,10,20,40,30};
    int W = 60;
    int n = val.length;
    System.out.println(knapSack(W, wt, val, n));
    }
}
```

What I did was create a 1-D array of type int to mark an index true if that value was chosen. Or at least, that's what I'm trying to do.

But this is printing every index. Until I figure that part out, I won't know how to also return the corresponding weights. I know my logic in the code is wrong so can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's very hard to set which items are selected as you go in a dynamic programming problem. As the solution necessarily builds off of solutions to sub-problems, you'd need to store the items selected in each of those sub-solutions as well, and then aggregate this at the end.

Luckily, there's a better way. We can backtrace using the final solution and see what values we ended up using. Simply replace the section where you print your values with:

```
System.out.println("\nItems selected : ");
int tempW = W;
int y = 0; //to index in selected
for (int x = n; x > 0; x--){
    if ((tempW-wt[x-1] >= 0) && (K[x][tempW] - K[x-1][tempW-wt[x-1]] == val[x-1]) ){
        selected[y++] = x-1; //store current index and increment y
        tempW-=wt[x-1];
    }
 }
 for(int j = y-1; j >= 0; j--){
    System.out.print("#" + (selected[j]+1) + " ");
    System.out.println(val[selected[j]]);
}
```

This will print:

```
Items selected:
#2 60
#3 90
#5 240
390
```

To print the items out in ascending order, we must store them and print them in a separate `for` loop. This is for the same reason we must backtrace in the first place: from the starting point there are many paths to take, while from the ending point there is only one path back to the start.

Comment: thanks! I just saw this! I've been trying to figure out how to print it in numerical order but have had no luck. I've tried reversing the loop but still can't seem to get it. I want the output to show #2, #3, and then #5 in that order.

Comment: I already tried storing it, and then having the values print out. But Let me actually try something else. Thank you, take your time. I will also try and see if I can get it!